# how can i retrieve all the enterprise applications form the azure active directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

how can i able to display the application details form the enterprise applicaiton.I need the application details from the register enterprise applications.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? If still have any problem, please let me know. If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could list [service principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#service-principal-object)(i.e. enterprise applicaitons) with Azure PowerShell [`Get-AzADServicePrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-5.8.0), and it returns some properties like this.

```
PS /home/xxx> Get-AzADServicePrincipal

ServicePrincipalNames : xxx
ApplicationId         : xxx
ObjectType            : ServicePrincipal
DisplayName           : xxx
Id                    : xxx
Type                  :

...
```

---

You could also [list service principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using **Microsoft Graph API**. It returns the servicePrincipal collection, and the properties of servicePrincipal are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals
```

You can test it in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#), **make sure** you have added the required [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) like `Application.ReadWrite.All`.